# Polynomial time algorithm for finding the chromatic sum of a tree.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees, coloring

As the title goes, a polynomial time algorithm for finding the chromatic sum of a tree is required.

**NOTE:**

Finding the chromatic sum of a graph is also called the sum coloring problem - The sum coloring problem asks to find a vertex coloring of a given graph G, using natural numbers, such that the total sum of the colors is minimized.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient linear-time algorithm for trees is given in:

[Kubicka, Ewa, and Allen J. Schwenk. "An introduction to chromatic sums." Proceedings of the 17th conference on ACM Annual Computer Science Conference. ACM, 1989.](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~skmanish/p39-kubicka.pdf)

Look at the last 2 pages.